# django models: more efficient way to retrieve objects via OneToOne relationship

Tags: django-models, one-to-one

I am using two models, one is User (from django.contrib.auth.models) and the other is Privilege:

```
class Privilege(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

I am able to retrieve the user's `privilege`:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
if user:
    privilege = Privilege.objects.get(user=user)
```

My question: does it always take two database operations to obtain the `privilege` object? Can I do it in just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have to manually do the second query, you can simply traverse the relationship:

```
try:
    privilege = User.objects.get(username=request.user).privilege
except User.DoesNotExist # Use this with get()
    pass
```

but it will do the second query in the background.

So, you can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to make the reverse traversal more efficient (i.e. 1 query)

> **select_related**: Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

```
privilege = User.objects.select_related("privilege").get(username=request.user).privilege
```